# Filament v3 - Is it possible to change css variable for sidebar-width

Tags: tailwind-css, themes, filamentphp

Is changing the css var for sidebar-width possible? I can't seem to locate any of those css variable definitions.

Documentation mentions about colors but I don't seem able to change them either. Docs mention targeting the classes eg fi-sidebar w-[--sidebar-width]

From the browser dev tools the sidebar width is 20rem, I would like it to be 12rem.

Can anyone shed some more light on the restyling process?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers\Filament;

class AdminPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
    public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
    {
        $panel->sidebarWidth('12rem');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**